# How to add two additional pages to a PDF with one image on each page with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, buffer

I have a PDF as buffer and two images as base64 string. I would like to add two pages at the end of the PDF and add one of the two images on each of the new pages.

How can this be done? I was looking into `jsPDF` but seems like it's not possible to achieve what I need with it.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

What about using PDF Tools (https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-tools.html) and the following APIs:

- Generate a PDF for each image (https://opensource.adobe.com/pdftools-sdk-docs/release/latest/howtos.html#create-a-pdf)
- Merge the 3 PDFs (your first, plus the two for image) (using insert - https://opensource.adobe.com/pdftools-sdk-docs/release/latest/howtos.html#insert-pages)

This is a commercial service (and I work for Adobe, FYI), but you can try it for free to see if it works for you. There's a Node SDK as well.